# Replace nth occurence of a character by another

Tags: regex, r

I hope this isn't a duplicated, I didn't find an answer and I need help from regexp wizards.

I have a string and I would like to replace the second space found in it by a `\n`, but I don't know how to use indices (this way) in a regular expression :

For example :

```
# I have :
"a b c d e f"
# I want :
> "a b/nc d e f"
```

Also I would like to know how I can "repeat" this replacement: each two occurences of space replace by `\n`. 
For example :

```
"a b c d e f"
> "a b\nc d\ne f"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(\\S+\\s+\\S+)\\s+
```

You can use this and replace by `\1\n` or `$1\n`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/yG7zB9/29